# How to configure dd-wrt router, for internet connection from other router in other subnet?

Tags: lan, dd-wrt

I can not solve this problem.

There modem / router (192.168.1.1) with wifi which distributes online. There wifi and router with dd-wrt, which must also distribute the Internet, but in the subnet 192.168.2.1.

How to configure a router with dd-wrt, that it was possible to connect by cable to the lan port of the first router (192.168.1.1) and when connected to the router on which the dd-wrt on lan or wifi, the device receives from the network ip 192.168.2.X and have access to the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should have to do is change the router's LAN address to 192.168.2.1 and adjust the DHCP range and similar parameters to match. All other parameters (other than configuring things you specifically need) can stay at their defaults. Then connect the new router's WAN port to one of the modem/router's LAN ports.

Comment: I tried, and i get ip from 192.168.2.x subnet, but i have not internet connection.

How i need configure wan connection on dd-wrt router?

Comment: @Buboon The default setting should be fine. It should get its IP using DHCP. (If that's not the default for some reason, set it to get its IP and other settings automatically.)

Comment: Maybe you can give screenshot, please ?

Comment: Like [this](http://blog.dotkam.com/wp-content/uploadhere/2008/09/setup-basic-setup-dd-wrt.jpeg), set the WAN connection to DHCP. Use the settings in that picture except change 10,2,1 to 192,168,2.